# Querying MySQL in PHP with a '0' value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a radio button that has two values; 0 and 1. The radio button comes through in PHP using the the variable `$activity = ($_POST['activity'];`

The query in PHP is set as:

```
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE activity = '$activity'";
```

This constrains the rows where the activity column equals '1' values, but doesn't work for '0' values. Instead it brings up all the records.

Any ideas what I'm missing? I've tried `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE activity = '0'` in MySQL itself and that works fine, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the PHP code.

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: what's the type of the activity field?

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis: `$activity = ($_POST['activity']);`.

Comment: If it's not selected, you are getting empty, not 0.

Comment: @ChristianStewart Switching to MySQLi doesn't necessarily mean switch to prepared statements. NodeJS is something very different.

Comment: just "switching" to mysqli doesn't do anything at all unless you fundamentally alter how you build/run queries. mysqli is not a magical cure that can make `SELECT * FROM x WHERE y = $_POST['foo']` "secure".

Comment: Many thanks for all of your comments. What I haven't shown you is how I've sanitized the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast that to `int` and protect your database as well (field datatype is not string or so):

```
if (isset($_POST['activity'])){
    $activity = (int) $_POST['activity'] ;
    "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE activity = {$activity} ";
    //And more
} else {
    echo "Nothing posted" ;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is Turkish proverb says "feed the crow, beats the eyes"...

```
$activity = intval($_POST['activity']);
```

Comment: uh, if $activity is `0`, then the query will end up with `= '0'`. It's true that in PHP `'' == 0` is true, but OP isn't doing any equality testing... just straight assignments, and PHP will **NOT** do that kind of mangling on simple assignment.